# Create MS Teams meeting from background job using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In my organization, we use Hangfire for background jobs and we've a recurring job that should create MS Teams meetings based on some conditions without any interaction from the user so we'll use application/client credentials but I can't find a way to do that without signed-in user

Is this supported somehow using MS Graph SDK?

Comment: You can create a online meeting using graph API. Could you please go through the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I tried to do so already but it doesn't work with client credentials

Comment: @Mahdy, You need to implement authentication. Please check this [auth docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts)